# Need help centering content of a footer

Tags: html, css

I have this footer that I Made and I want all of the icons links and the name to be centered vertically and horizontally I was able to get it so that they are centered horizontally

I have tried to set the position to relative and put "top: 50%;" but that just pushes all of the footers content out of it

```css
footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-top: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #3C8DAD;
}
.footer-name {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 5em;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: clamp(1.2em, 1.3vw, 4em);
}
.pages, .pages a {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-size: clamp(1.2em, 1.3vw, 4em);
}
.icons {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.icons a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.footer-line {
  height: 75%;
  width: 3px;
  align-self: center;
  background-color: #f5a962;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  footer {
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .footer-name, .pages, .icons {
    width: inherit;
    margin: 0px;
  }
  .footer-line {
    height: 3px;
    width: 75%;
  }
}
```

```html
<footer>
<div class="footer-name">
   NAME
</div>
<div class="footer-line"></div>

<div class="pages">
     <div><a href="#">Home</a></div>
    <div><a href="#">About Me</a></div>
    <div><a href="#">Projects</a></div>
    <div><a href="#">Contact Me</a></div> 
</div>

<div class="footer-line"></div>

<div class="icons">
  <a target="_blank" href="https://github.com/AndrewSae"><?xml version="1.0"?><svg fill="#000000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 30 30" width="50px" height="50px">    <path d="M15,3C8.373,3,3,8.373,3,15c0,5.623,3.872,10.328,9.092,11.63C12.036,26.468,12,26.28,12,26.047v-2.051 c-0.487,0-1.303,0-1.508,0c-0.821,0-1.551-0.353-1.905-1.009c-0.393-0.729-0.461-1.844-1.435-2.526 c-0.289-0.227-0.069-0.486,0.264-0.451c0.615,0.174,1.125,0.596,1.605,1.222c0.478,0.627,0.703,0.769,1.596,0.769 c0.433,0,1.081-0.025,1.691-0.121c0.328-0.833,0.895-1.6,1.588-1.962c-3.996-0.411-5.903-2.399-5.903-5.098 c0-1.162,0.495-2.286,1.336-3.233C9.053,10.647,8.706,8.73,9.435,8c1.798,0,2.885,1.166,3.146,1.481C13.477,9.174,14.461,9,15.495,9 c1.036,0,2.024,0.174,2.922,0.483C18.675,9.17,19.763,8,21.565,8c0.732,0.731,0.381,2.656,0.102,3.594 c0.836,0.945,1.328,2.066,1.328,3.226c0,2.697-1.904,4.684-5.894,5.097C18.199,20.49,19,22.1,19,23.313v2.734 c0,0.104-0.023,0.179-0.035,0.268C23.641,24.676,27,20.236,27,15C27,8.373,21.627,3,15,3z"/></svg>
  </a>
  <a target="_blank" href="#"><svg fill="#000000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 50 50" width="50px" height="50px"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M 40.925781 1.890625 L 37.859375 2.417969 L 41.1875 20.625 L 44.03125 20.253906 Z M 29.96875 6.351563 L 27.101563 8.078125 L 37.300781 23.035156 L 39.820313 21.480469 Z M 20.796875 15.03125 L 19.113281 17.703125 L 34.5 27 L 35.902344 24.578125 Z M 16.375 24.402344 L 15.628906 27.402344 L 33.359375 31.894531 L 33.640625 29.203125 Z M 9 29 L 9 47.984375 L 38.902344 48 L 38.902344 47.984375 C 38.933594 47.984375 39 29 39 29 L 36 29 L 36 45 L 12 45 L 12 29 Z M 15.152344 32.355469 L 14.902344 35.339844 L 33 37 L 33.203125 34.5 Z M 14.902344 39 L 15 42 L 33 41.929688 L 33 39 Z"/></svg>
  </a>
  <a target="_blank" href="#"><?xml version="1.0"?><svg fill="#000000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 30 30" width="50px" height="50px">    <path d="M24,4H6C4.895,4,4,4.895,4,6v18c0,1.105,0.895,2,2,2h18c1.105,0,2-0.895,2-2V6C26,4.895,25.105,4,24,4z M10.954,22h-2.95 v-9.492h2.95V22z M9.449,11.151c-0.951,0-1.72-0.771-1.72-1.72c0-0.949,0.77-1.719,1.72-1.719c0.948,0,1.719,0.771,1.719,1.719 C11.168,10.38,10.397,11.151,9.449,11.151z M22.004,22h-2.948v-4.616c0-1.101-0.02-2.517-1.533-2.517 c-1.535,0-1.771,1.199-1.771,2.437V22h-2.948v-9.492h2.83v1.297h0.04c0.394-0.746,1.356-1.533,2.791-1.533 c2.987,0,3.539,1.966,3.539,4.522V22z"/></svg>
  </a>
  <a target="_blank" href="#"><?xml version="1.0"?><svg fill="#000000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 30 30" width="50px" height="50px">    <path d="M24,4H6C4.895,4,4,4.895,4,6v18c0,1.105,0.895,2,2,2h10v-9h-3v-3h3v-1.611C16,9.339,17.486,8,20.021,8 c1.214,0,1.856,0.09,2.16,0.131V11h-1.729C19.376,11,19,11.568,19,12.718V14h3.154l-0.428,3H19v9h5c1.105,0,2-0.895,2-2V6 C26,4.895,25.104,4,24,4z"/></svg>
  </a>
  <a target="_blank" href="#"><?xml version="1.0"?><svg fill="#000000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 30 30" width="50px" height="50px">    <path d="M 9.9980469 3 C 6.1390469 3 3 6.1419531 3 10.001953 L 3 20.001953 C 3 23.860953 6.1419531 27 10.001953 27 L 20.001953 27 C 23.860953 27 27 23.858047 27 19.998047 L 27 9.9980469 C 27 6.1390469 23.858047 3 19.998047 3 L 9.9980469 3 z M 22 7 C 22.552 7 23 7.448 23 8 C 23 8.552 22.552 9 22 9 C 21.448 9 21 8.552 21 8 C 21 7.448 21.448 7 22 7 z M 15 9 C 18.309 9 21 11.691 21 15 C 21 18.309 18.309 21 15 21 C 11.691 21 9 18.309 9 15 C 9 11.691 11.691 9 15 9 z M 15 11 A 4 4 0 0 0 11 15 A 4 4 0 0 0 15 19 A 4 4 0 0 0 19 15 A 4 4 0 0 0 15 11 z"/></svg>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this is what you're looking for:

```css
footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #3C8DAD;
}
.footer-name, .pages, .icons {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.footer-name {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: clamp(1.2em, 1.3vw, 4em);
}
.pages, .pages a {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-size: clamp(1.2em, 1.3vw, 4em);
}
.icons {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.icons a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.footer-line {
  height: 75%;
  width: 3px;
  align-self: center;
  background-color: #f5a962;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  footer {
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .footer-name, .pages, .icons {
    width: inherit;
    margin: 0px;
  }
  .footer-line {
    height: 3px;
    width: 75%;
  }
}
```

```html
<footer>
<div class="footer-name">
   NAME
</div>
<div class="footer-line"></div>

<div class="pages">
     <div><a href="#">Home</a></div>
    <div><a href="#">About Me</a></div>
    <div><a href="#">Projects</a></div>
    <div><a href="#">Contact Me</a></div> 
</div>

<div class="footer-line"></div>

<div class="icons">
  <a target="_blank" href="https://github.com/AndrewSae"><?xml version="1.0"?><svg fill="#000000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 30 30" width="50px" height="50px">    <path d="M15,3C8.373,3,3,8.373,3,15c0,5.623,3.872,10.328,9.092,11.63C12.036,26.468,12,26.28,12,26.047v-2.051 c-0.487,0-1.303,0-1.508,0c-0.821,0-1.551-0.353-1.905-1.009c-0.393-0.729-0.461-1.844-1.435-2.526 c-0.289-0.227-0.069-0.486,0.264-0.451c0.615,0.174,1.125,0.596,1.605,1.222c0.478,0.627,0.703,0.769,1.596,0.769 c0.433,0,1.081-0.025,1.691-0.121c0.328-0.833,0.895-1.6,1.588-1.962c-3.996-0.411-5.903-2.399-5.903-5.098 c0-1.162,0.495-2.286,1.336-3.233C9.053,10.647,8.706,8.73,9.435,8c1.798,0,2.885,1.166,3.146,1.481C13.477,9.174,14.461,9,15.495,9 c1.036,0,2.024,0.174,2.922,0.483C18.675,9.17,19.763,8,21.565,8c0.732,0.731,0.381,2.656,0.102,3.594 c0.836,0.945,1.328,2.066,1.328,3.226c0,2.697-1.904,4.684-5.894,5.097C18.199,20.49,19,22.1,19,23.313v2.734 c0,0.104-0.023,0.179-0.035,0.268C23.641,24.676,27,20.236,27,15C27,8.373,21.627,3,15,3z"/></svg>
  </a>
  <a target="_blank" href="#"><svg fill="#000000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 50 50" width="50px" height="50px"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M 40.925781 1.890625 L 37.859375 2.417969 L 41.1875 20.625 L 44.03125 20.253906 Z M 29.96875 6.351563 L 27.101563 8.078125 L 37.300781 23.035156 L 39.820313 21.480469 Z M 20.796875 15.03125 L 19.113281 17.703125 L 34.5 27 L 35.902344 24.578125 Z M 16.375 24.402344 L 15.628906 27.402344 L 33.359375 31.894531 L 33.640625 29.203125 Z M 9 29 L 9 47.984375 L 38.902344 48 L 38.902344 47.984375 C 38.933594 47.984375 39 29 39 29 L 36 29 L 36 45 L 12 45 L 12 29 Z M 15.152344 32.355469 L 14.902344 35.339844 L 33 37 L 33.203125 34.5 Z M 14.902344 39 L 15 42 L 33 41.929688 L 33 39 Z"/></svg>
  </a>
  <a target="_blank" href="#"><?xml version="1.0"?><svg fill="#000000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 30 30" width="50px" height="50px">    <path d="M24,4H6C4.895,4,4,4.895,4,6v18c0,1.105,0.895,2,2,2h18c1.105,0,2-0.895,2-2V6C26,4.895,25.105,4,24,4z M10.954,22h-2.95 v-9.492h2.95V22z M9.449,11.151c-0.951,0-1.72-0.771-1.72-1.72c0-0.949,0.77-1.719,1.72-1.719c0.948,0,1.719,0.771,1.719,1.719 C11.168,10.38,10.397,11.151,9.449,11.151z M22.004,22h-2.948v-4.616c0-1.101-0.02-2.517-1.533-2.517 c-1.535,0-1.771,1.199-1.771,2.437V22h-2.948v-9.492h2.83v1.297h0.04c0.394-0.746,1.356-1.533,2.791-1.533 c2.987,0,3.539,1.966,3.539,4.522V22z"/></svg>
  </a>
  <a target="_blank" href="#"><?xml version="1.0"?><svg fill="#000000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 30 30" width="50px" height="50px">    <path d="M24,4H6C4.895,4,4,4.895,4,6v18c0,1.105,0.895,2,2,2h10v-9h-3v-3h3v-1.611C16,9.339,17.486,8,20.021,8 c1.214,0,1.856,0.09,2.16,0.131V11h-1.729C19.376,11,19,11.568,19,12.718V14h3.154l-0.428,3H19v9h5c1.105,0,2-0.895,2-2V6 C26,4.895,25.104,4,24,4z"/></svg>
  </a>
  <a target="_blank" href="#"><?xml version="1.0"?><svg fill="#000000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 30 30" width="50px" height="50px">    <path d="M 9.9980469 3 C 6.1390469 3 3 6.1419531 3 10.001953 L 3 20.001953 C 3 23.860953 6.1419531 27 10.001953 27 L 20.001953 27 C 23.860953 27 27 23.858047 27 19.998047 L 27 9.9980469 C 27 6.1390469 23.858047 3 19.998047 3 L 9.9980469 3 z M 22 7 C 22.552 7 23 7.448 23 8 C 23 8.552 22.552 9 22 9 C 21.448 9 21 8.552 21 8 C 21 7.448 21.448 7 22 7 z M 15 9 C 18.309 9 21 11.691 21 15 C 21 18.309 18.309 21 15 21 C 11.691 21 9 18.309 9 15 C 9 11.691 11.691 9 15 9 z M 15 11 A 4 4 0 0 0 11 15 A 4 4 0 0 0 15 19 A 4 4 0 0 0 19 15 A 4 4 0 0 0 15 11 z"/></svg>
  </a>
</div>
```